# Cannot use my custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a web application with 2 projects: the website itself and a project containing custom server controls.

I referenced the server control project in my web app, and added this to my web.config:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="ServerControls" tagName="MyControl" tagPrefix="sc" namespace="ServerControls" />
  </controls>      
</pages>
```

But how do I use the control? It's not showing up in the toolbox or intellisense and is giving me an error when I start it up in the web.config.

Comment: Are we talking about control classes (.cs or .vb) or user controls (.ascx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check that your custom control class is marked public or it will not be visible from outside the assembly.

Then just reference it in the page like this:

```
<sc:MyControl runat="server" />
```

You shouldn't need a Register directive on the page because you have already registered the tag prefix in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the tag name and then use the tag:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" TagName="[control]" 
    Src="~/Controls/control.ascx" %>
```

At the top of the page and then use the control like this:

```
<sc:Control id="id" runat="server" />
```